# Create a shared mailbox in Exchange through an API

Tags: exchange-server

I'm developing an API that should be able to create a shared mailbox in exchange.  So far the only documentation I found around this is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-mailbox?view=exchange-ps, and this uses PowerShell.  Invoking PowerShell from an API is not easy, I'm wondering if there is a direct API call I can use for this, preferably MSGraph (I did some searching on this but could not find an endpoint)